# std::ifstream::operator>> cannot translate 0xABCD into a short?

Tags: c++, binary, std

I'm trying to read a binary file which is a series of bytes and longs encoded in little endian format.
I had assumed that I could use an ifstream opened in ios::binary mode for this, but apparently I cannot: When I try to read a long, it sets the failbit and throws an exception.
I do not understand why it is doing this.
This is my code:

```
std::string fname = (
        boost::format(
            (
                boost::filesystem::initial_path()
                / "maps"
                / "w%02d.map"
            )
            .string() 
        )
        % mapNum
    )
    .str();
if (!boost::filesystem::exists(fname))
    throw std::runtime_error("No such map " + fname + "!");

std::ifstream file;
file.exceptions(std::ifstream::eofbit | std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
file.open(fname, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

char header[4];
file.read(header, 4);
if (!(header[0] == '!' && header[1] == 'I' && header[2] == 'D' && header[3] == '!'))
    throw std::runtime_error(fname + " is not a valida map file!");

unsigned short int RLEWtag = 0;
file >> RLEWtag;
```

and these are the first 10 bytes of the file: `21 49 44 21 CD AB 40 00 40 00`
If it matters, I'm running this in VS2010 on 64 bit Windows 7.

Comment: ¤ `operator>>` is a conversion from textual specification, to a value of the relevant type. The stream's binary mode does not matter for this translation: it matters only on a deeper level, for translation of newlines and end of file markers. So, you're asking `operator>>` to assume that the byte values 0xCD 0xAB ... are a textual specification of an integer. That fails outright on the first byte. But you can use `read` to perform an *unformatted read* operation, i.e. a "binary read". Note that `read` only works as a binary read operation when the stream is in binary mode. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using formatted input (i.e. the stream extraction operator, `operator>>`), which expects textual data; instead you need to use *un*formatted input, just as you did to read the header:

```
unsigned short RLEWtag;
char buf[2];
file.read(buf, 2);
std::memcpy(&RLEWtag, buf, 2);
```

Or, more succinctly (thanks @KerrekSB),

```
unsigned short RLEWtag;
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&RLEWtag), 2);
```

Comment: is shorter version `unsigned short RLEWtag = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(buf);` valid?

Comment: @AndyT : No -- technically, that exhibits undefined behavior. While it tends to work fine in practice, when using GCC with strict-aliasing enabled it will yield a compiler warning then fail miserably at runtime.

Comment: The short version is `file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&RLEWtag), 2);`.